# SQLite query with two where

Tags: android, sqlite, android-sqlite

I am trying to get data from my sqlite database, according to two arguments , type and name.
I tried a lot of solutions but none of them worked.
that is my query

```
   ...
   mCursor = db.query(false,TABLE_SERVICE, new String[] {KEY_ID,KEY_NAME,
               KEY_ADRESSE, KEY_EMAIL, KEY_NUMTEL, KEY_WEBSITE,KEY_IMAGE},
               KEY_NAME
                + " like ? and " + KEY_TYPE+ " like ?",
                new String[] {inputText,c}, null, null, null,null);
      }
      if (mCursor != null) {
       mCursor.moveToFirst();
      }
      return mCursor;
     ....
```

i've also tried :

```
KET_NAME + "=" + inputText+ " AND " + KEY_TYPE + "=" + c
```

and this

```
KEY_NAME + " = '" + inputText+ "' AND " + KEY_TYPE + " = '" + c+ "'"
```

and nothing worked ! i'm getting an empty cursor.

Comment: What are the values of `inputText` and `c`, and what are the actual column or a record that you think should match?

Answer (score 1):

Please note that `LIKE` doesn't work the same way as `=`. `LIKE` takes a matching pattern as parameter, such as "%query%" (meaning anything containing the word "query"). LIKE is most likely used for performing searches from human input, looking for partial matches and being case insensitive. If you know the exact value of your parameter, then you should use `=` which is also faster.

Also, `query()` never returns `null` so it's unnecessary to test for `null`.

Your code seems correct so if your query returns an empty Cursor it's simply because nothing matches your query in your current database.

Comment: thanks for the explanation, I did nit knew that! my query is works when I use one argument.. I will try other things and see. thank you